# About crossed product of the group von Neumann algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $G$ be a group with a normal subgroup $N$. If $K$ is a field, then it is well known in ring theory that $K[G]\cong K[N]*(G/N)$ ($*$ stands for the crossed product). Do we have such an isomorphism in the group von Neumann algebra setting? i.e. Does there exist an action of $G/N$ on $W(N)$, such that von Neumann algebras $W(G)$ and $W(N)\rtimes(G/N)$ become isomorphic? Here, $W(G)$ is the group von Neumann algebra of $G$.

Comment: It would be safer to assume the group to be locally compact, because a measure is required to define the von Neumann it generates. Usual notations are $L(G)$ or $W^*(G)$. If $G$ is finite $L(G) \simeq \mathbb{C}[G]$. Now if you consider directly a group $G \subset \mathcal{U}(H)$ with $H$ separable Hilbert space, you can directly consider the von Neumann algebra $G''$. In any case, you should  at least check that the action of $G/N$ on $\mathbb{C}[N]$ is compatible with the $*$-structure and continuous for the [weak operator topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_operator_topology).

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux How $G/N$ acts on $\mathbb CN$?

Comment: What I mean is: start from the result in ring theory you talked about, and take its action of $G/N$ on $K[N]$. Then take $K=\mathbb{C}$ and check whether this action is compatible with the von Neumann algebra structure (as I wrote at the end of my previous comment).